# Colored image will become black and white

Tags: java, image

For a project of mine, which is targeting java 6, I had been in the need to have different algorithms/methods to change a `BufferdImage` with a `ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB` to a plain ole black and white one.

To test these implementations I therefore created an interface

```
public interface BlackAndWhiteConverter {
    BufferedImage toBlackAndWhite(BufferedImage image);
    void setThreshold(int threshold);
}
```

and the, for me, most successful implementation is up for review

```
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

public class BlackAndWhiteRedThresholdConverter implements BlackAndWhiteConverter {

    @Override
    public BufferedImage toBlackAndWhite(final BufferedImage image) {

        final int imageType = image.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType();

        if (imageType != ColorSpace.TYPE_RGB) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        final int width = image.getWidth();
        final int height = image.getHeight();
        final int upperLimit = width * height;

        final DataBuffer buffer = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
        final int[] source = ((DataBufferInt) buffer).getData();

        byte[] destination = new byte[upperLimit];

        for (int i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++) {

            int red = (source[i] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;

            if (red > threshold) {
                destination[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 1, 2, null);
        raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, destination);

        BufferedImage destinationImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        destinationImage.setData(raster);
        return destinationImage;
    }

    private int threshold = 110;

    @Override
    public void setThreshold(int threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }


}
```

Please comment on anything that springs into your face. No matter what, I can't use a java version higher than 6.

Comment: I like your verbose style of declaring local variables `final`, yet many times I heard people complaining about it. For consistency, you should declare also `raster` and friends `final`.

Comment: Just to make this clear, you only care about the red level in the original image?  So an image of a green circle will turn completely black?

Comment: @JS1 if another algorithmn will get me the same result than thats fine. I need this converter to get black letters on grey background for ocr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Input validation

If the received image is not RGB, throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` without a custom message is not very friendly. Users would have to look at the code to understand what went wrong exactly.

The long chain `image.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType()` is extracted to an `imageType` local variable that's only used for validation.
I would be good to move the validation to a dedicated helper method, let's say `validateImageType`.

#### Java conventions

Member variables should be declared at the top, followed by constructors, followed by methods. Very roughly speaking. So move the declaration of `threshold` higher.

#### Naming

As the interface name already implies the conversion to black and white,
the method name `toBlackAndWhite` is redundant. I'd rename it to simply `convert`.

#### Misc

`0x000000FF` is the same as `0xFF`, so you can shorten it.

Comment: I disagree with changing the method name to simply `convert`. It's fine as it is. Many future interfaces could use the signature `BufferedImage convert(BufferedImage)` because it's so generic.

Answer (score 4):

#### Taking into account other colors

In case your input images aren't just grayscale images, you may need to take into account colors other than red.  The standard RGB to grayscale formula looks like this:

```
gray = (red * 0.3 + green * 0.59 + blue * 0.11)
```

You can approximate that without using floating point like this:

```
gray = (red*3 + green*6 + blue) / 10
```

So your loop would look like this:

```
    int grayThreshold = threshold * 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++) {

        int red   = (source[i] >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int green = (source[i] >>  8) & 0xFF;
        int blue  = (source[i])       & 0xFF;
        int gray  = red*3 + green*6 + blue;

        if (gray > grayThreshold) {
            destination[i] = -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is that this isn't very object-oriented. There's only one field and you can very easily refactor the class so that it doesn't need it:

```
public abstract class BlackAndWhiteRedThresholdConverter implements BlackAndWhiteConverter {

    public static BufferedImage toBlackAndWhite(final BufferedImage image, final int threshold) {
        // convert
    }

    @Override
    public static BufferedImage toBlackAndWhite(final BufferedImage image) {
        return toBlackAndWhite(image, 110);
    }
}
```

This class is slightly easier to use than yours. There's no need to instantiate, and I can still use either my own threshold or the default one. Basically though it's no different. However, it's easier to see from this class definition that *it's not object-oriented*. It's procedural. It ends with "-er" [and that's often bad](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html).

A better solution might involve extending `BufferedImage`. Now when I instantiate a `BlackAndWhiteImage` I get a proper object who is actually useful.

```
public class BlackAndWhiteImage extends BufferedImage
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 110;

    public static BlackAndWhiteImage make(final BufferedImage image, final int threshold)
    {
        return toBlackAndWhite(image, threshold);
    }

    public static BlackAndWhiteImage make(final BufferedImage image)
    {
        return make(image, DEFAULT_THRESHOLD);
    }

    /* Private constructor to create underlying BufferedImage */ 
    private BlackAndWhiteImage(ColorModel colourModel, WritableRaster raster, boolean alphaPremult)
    {
        super(colourModel, raster, alphaPremult, null);
    }

    private static BlackAndWhiteImage toBlackAndWhite(final BufferedImage image, final int threshold)
    {
        /* Conversion stuff is all the same */
        return new BlackAndWhiteImage( destinationImage.getColorModel(),
                                       destinationImage.getRaster(),
                                       destinationImage.isAlphaPremultiplied() );
    }
}
```

The static factory methods (`make`) are unfortunate but I couldn't get around using them.

Example usage:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
BlackAndWhiteImage bw = BlackAndWhiteImage.make(img);

File outputfile = new File("");
ImageIO.write(bw, "jpg", outputfile);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Sure it seems preferable to remove the one and only field but then I need to passs each time the threshold wether it had changed or not. Because I use [SIMON](http://dev.root1.de/projects/simon/wiki) I need to use an interface so the methods can be called remotely hence extending `BufferedImage` is not an option because both the server and the client would need to know about this concrete implementation. Nevertheless +1

Comment: About the `-er`, I agree on vague names like `Controller`,  `Manager` etc. including `Converter` but having a `BlackAndWhiteConverter` is IMO ok.

Comment: The issue is that a "converter" is not really an object. It doesn't represent anything. It's conceptually no different from a function that converts one object to something else. I highly recommend the other articles on the site that I linked - he has some very interesting, if controversial, ideas.